# Substring.full not working in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to implement the `full` function of the `Substring` signature in the following way :

```
val x = Substring.full "straight"
```

The output returned is :

```
val x = - : substring
```

As I see, the function is not returning any value to the variable `x`.

What must be going wrong? *( I am using V110.77  of SML/NJ on Windows 8.1.)*

Comment: you try to implement? could you show us your code?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr : The code is written in the question. The function `full` is already defined in the signature `Substring`.

Comment: you mean you try to use. ok. try `Substring.string(Substring.full "straight");`. you over-concern.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr : Oops !! I am trying to 'use' the function. But what you are suggesting, will convert the substring back to string. I need to convert the string to just substring so that I can use the 'Substring.position' function, i.e. at the end, I am trying to use the 'Substring.position' function.

Comment: what my code did told you the string had been converted to a substring. you don't worry when it couldn't be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is fine. But substring is an abstract type, and values of abstract type cannot be printed by the SML/NJ prompt. So they are just indicated by "-".